# Select where date not in interval

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables

```
Payments:
| employeeID | period_begin  | period_end   |
```

and

```
Services:
| serviceID  | date      | employeeID   |
```

I need to find all serviceIDs performed by a given employee whose date is not between any of the period ranges described in Payments. So, for example if I have the following records on Payments and Services for employee 10000:

```
Payments:
| employeeID    | period_begin  | period_end    |
...
| 10000     | 2013-05-01    | 2013-05-16    |
| 10000     | 2013-05-17    | 2013-06-02    |
| 10000     | 2013-07-01    | 2013-07-16    |
| 10000     | 2013-07-17    | 2013-08-02    |   
...

Services:
| serviceID         | date          | employeeID    |
...
| 2001      | 2013-01-01    | 10000     |
| 2002      | 2013-05-15    | 10000     |
| 2003      | 2013-06-01    | 10000     |
| 2004      | 2013-07-10    | 10000     |
| 2005      | 2013-08-01    | 10000     |
...
```

The output should be

2001,
   2003,
   2005

because the dates for services 2002, 2004 are in one of the intervals in the Payments table.

Any ideas? I'm having trouble checking that a service's date is not accounted for one of the intervals recorded on the Payments table. I'm currently joining Services and Payments on employeeID and stating the date condition there, but I'm not getting the right answer; I should probably be joining on a different condition:

```
select distinct serviceID from Services as X left join Payments as Y on
(X.employeeID=Y.employeeID AND (X.date < Y.period_begin OR X.date > Y.period_end))
where X.employeeID='10000';
```

is not working.

Comment: Could you verify your example? According to your description "2003" shouldn't be in the output since 2013-06-01 is between 2013-05-17    and 2013-06-02. This is the same for 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the main problem which is "select the services not in *any* payment range" you could use a `LEFT JOIN` to keep only the row that does not have a corresponding payment range:

```
SELECT Services.* FROM Services
 LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT serviceID,period_begin FROM Services 
     JOIN Payments
     USING (employeeID)
     WHERE employeeID = @EID
     AND the_date BETWEEN Payments.period_begin AND Payments.period_end
  ) AS X
 USING (serviceID)
 WHERE employeeID = @EID
 AND period_begin is NULL;
```

Or, use a subquery -- somewhat more readable, but usually less efficient:

```
SELECT Services.* FROM Services
WHERE employeeID = @EID
AND serviceID NOT IN (SELECT serviceID FROM Services JOIN Payments
                      USING (employeeID)
                      WHERE employeeID = @EID
                      AND the_date BETWEEN Payments.period_begin AND Payments.period_end);
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3557/11

Answer (score 2):

```
... AND X.date < Y.period_begin and X.date > Y.period_end
```

Is obviously impossible (the date cannot be before the start date *and* after the end date...)

You probably want to write:

```
... AND (X.date < Y.period_begin or X.date > Y.period_end)
```

Please wrap the "OR" expression is parenthesis. I think this is important regarding operator precedence and it improves readability.

**EDIT:** As suggested by @BigToach in a comment, you could use `NOT BETWEEN ... AND ...` (if the `AND` word is not too confusing in that context):

```
... AND (X.date NOT BETWEEN Y.period_begin AND Y.period_end)
```

Comment: You can also do X.date NOT BETWEEN y.period_begin AND y.period_end

Comment: @BigToach Much cleaner indeed. My attempt was to put emphasis on the and/or thing. But you are right. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: As indicated by BigToach and Sylvain Leroux, there was clearly a logic-typo confusing an AND with an OR. However, once fixed, that query still doesn't give the right answer. I managed to get the right solution by first finding all serviceIDs contained in some date interval, and then excluding those from the list of all serviceIDs.
This new query is not very pretty though, as I'm really doing two queries. Is there a better way of doing it? I'll post the actual query in a couple hours.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by BigToach and Sylvain Leroux, there was clearly a logic-typo confusing an AND with an OR. However, once fixed, that query still doesn't give the right answer. I managed to get the right solution by first finding all serviceIDs for contained in some interval, and then excluding those from the list of all serviceIDs:

```
    select distinct serviceID from Services as X left join Payments as Y on
    (X.employeeID=Y.employeeID) where X.employeeID='10000' 
    and X.serviceID not in (
       select serviceID from Services as Z join Payments as W on
       (Z.employeeID=W.employeeID and 
       (Z.date between W.period_begin and W.period_end)) 
       where Z.employeeID='10000'
    );
```

This query, however, is not very pretty as I'm really doing two queries, but it's basically the same thing than Sylvain Leroux first answer, perhaps a bit more human-readable. Maybe there is yet another way we all haven't seen yet. Sylvain's subquery is indeed very nice.